# How do I switch to Classic controller control scheme?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

I've started playing Hyrule Warriors, and I'm trying to switch the control schemes.  It recognizes the Wiimote + Nunchuck combo just fine, but when I unplug it, and plug in the Classic controller, it doesn't light up like the gamepad or nunchuck options do.  Looking on the back of the packaging, the classic controller icon is there, but it doesn't work.  Do I have to do something special to make the Classic controller work?

Comment: you might need to check the controller settings in the options somewhere. I was quite frustrated myself when the pro controller did not work. You just have to change the controller settings...for the pro anyway. Worth looking into for the classic, especially since I have some also.

Answer (score 5):

The classic controller is not supported in Hyrule Warriors. You can use the Wii U Gamepad, Wii Remote + Nunchuck, or the Wii U Pro Controller.

[Source](http://e3.nintendo.com/games/wiiu/hyrule-warriors/)

Comment: This is rather disappointing, especially considering there seems to be no reason to exclude the classic controller beyond "screw you, buy the new peripheral."

Answer (score 2):

you need the Wii U pro controller, classic controller doesn't work [image]

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Could you provide a source, that states that only the Wii U pro controller is supported?

Answer (score -1):

Restart the game, and dont touch anything on the gamepad. when the title screen comes up, press a button on your controller FIRST. If that doesn't work, then I'm guessing that the classic controller is unsupported, but I have to follow those steps to get my pro contoller to work.

Answer (score -2):

Go to options and check your controller settings. It could require a restart of the system to recognize properly.